# Chrome console TypeError: Ext.getStore() is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a sencha touch project and i want to add a record to my store. here is my model :

```
Ext.define('FriendsWithBeer.model.Friend', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field',
    'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'firstName'
        },
        {
            name: 'lastName'
        },
        {
            name: 'address'
        },
        {
            name: 'zip'
        },
        {
            name: 'email'
        },
        {
            name: 'phone'
        },
        {
            name: 'favoriteBeer'
        },
        {
            name: 'lat'
        },
        {
            name: 'lng'
        },
        {
            name: 'distance'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'FriendsWithBeerContacts'
    }
}
});
```

my store is the following :

```
Ext.define('FriendsWithBeer.store.Friends', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'FriendsWithBeer.model.Friend',
    'Ext.util.Grouper'
],

config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'FriendsWithBeer.model.Friend',
    storeId: 'Friends',
    sorters: {
        property: 'lastName'
    },
    grouper: {
        groupFn: function(item) {
            return item.get('lastName')[0];
        }
    }
}
});
```

Now, in my chrome console, I've entered :

```
Ext.getStore('Friends').add(
{firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Drucker'}
);
```

so i have the following error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

can you please help me ?

Comment: FWIW, the error is telling you one of three things: 1. Either `Ext.getStore` is `undefined`, or 2. `Ext.getStore('Friends')` returns an object on which `add` is `undefined`, or 3. Something `getStore` or `add` *calls* tries to use `undefined` as a function. I don't know ExtJS enough to tell you which...

Comment: I think that Ext.getStore() is undefined

Comment: it's OK i've resolved this. I added the sencha touch library path in my project library

Comment: Ah, good! FWIW, I would suggest doing a quick experiment to be sure which thing it was that was `undefined`, update the question to be specific about that, and then post an answer saying what you did to fix it. You'll be able to accept that answer in two days.

Comment: the solution is : go to Library Base Path in your sencha touch project and add the path to your sencha touch library.

Comment: Right, so post it as an *answer*. Look around SO to see how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is : go to Library Base Path in your sencha touch project and add the path to your sencha touch library.